# Not able to copy a file from one location on a share to another on the same share, no credentials needed

Tags: c#

The big difference between this question and all the others out there is that the network share I want to copy a file on DOES NOT require credentials. I can map a drive to that share without entering a username and password and it works just fine. Here's my code:

```
try
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"\\UTMSFP23\GROUP\1217\");
    File.Copy(@"\\UTMSFP23\GROUP\1217\IS_TEMPLATE.xlsx", @"\\UTMSFP23\GROUP\1217\IS_" + todayFormatted2 + ".xlsx");
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
}
```

I can open a file explorer window to the directory I'm copying in but as soon as the debugger hits the file copy line it goes into the catch block and gives the following error:

System.IO.IOException: Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.

I don't understand how I can map a drive to that share without entering credentials, open a file explorer to that very directory with no username or password but I can't copy a file in that directory to the same directory with a different name. I checked the security permissions on the template file to see if that was it but it has full control granted to everyone. Can someone help me out?

Comment: This code is in your site, not console app isn't it?

Comment: What kind of application it is? Web application, Windows form or console applicatiion?

Comment: I'm running a c# console application.

Answer (score 0):

what does the Console.WriteLine(e.ToString()); say when it enters the catch? This may give you some clue as to the permissions problem that you are having?

Comment: I mentioned that in my original post:  System.IO.IOException: Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.
But this doesn't make sense seeing as I don't need any credentials to log on to this share, hence my question.

Answer (score -1):

Is this a network drive? because if it is there is a cluster that goes with it. It's not just some file path and that is it. Also, Usually there is a drive letter assigned to it when it is mapped. I don't see any drive letter in your file path or is this the part of the code I am not seeing. If your on a network and you have multiple computers assigned doesn't mean it is always the same drive letter either because of how it is mapped.